# How to automatically save PowerShell session

Tags: powershell, logging, transcription

How can i redirect everything what happens within a PowerShell windows (inputs and outputs) automatically to a file? I don't mean single commands instead i would like to have something like a logger which captures everything and logs into a local file so that i have a history of things done within the powershell window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for PowerShell's [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) cmdlet, which:

> creates a record of all or part of a Windows PowerShell session to a text file. The transcript includes all command that the user types and all output that appears on the console.

Running transcripts must be stopped explicitly, with the [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript) cmdlet.